# How to wait until the async CopyHere (Shell API command) completing the ZIP compression?

Tags: delphi, winapi, asynchronous, process, zip

I need to Zip and Unzip files in Delphi without using a 3rd party component.
How to wait until the async CopyHere completing the ZIP compression?

**The following code is not working perfectly.**

Code to zipping files using ShellAPI

```
procedure TShellZip.ZipFolder(const SourceFolder: WideString);
var
  SrcFldr, DestFldr: OleVariant;
  ShellFldrItems: Olevariant;
  NumT: Integer;
begin
  if not FileExists(ZipFile) then
  begin
    CreateEmptyZip;
  end;

  NumT := NumProcessThreads;
  ShellObj := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
  SrcFldr := GetNameSpaceObj(SourceFolder);

  if not IsValidDispatch(SrcFldr) then
  begin
    raise EInvalidOperation.CreateFmt('<%s> Local de origem inválido.', [SourceFolder]);
  end;

  DestFldr := GetNameSpaceObj_ZipFile;
  ShellFldrItems := SrcFldr.Items;

  if (Filter <> '') then
  begin
    ShellFldrItems.Filter(SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN or SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS or SHCONTF_FOLDERS, Filter);
  end;

  DestFldr.CopyHere(ShellFldrItems, SHCONTCH_NOPROGRESSBOX or SHCONTCH_RESPONDYESTOALL);

  //wailt async processes
  while NumProcessThreads <> NumT do
  begin
    Sleep(100);
  end;
end;
```

Code to count processes

```
function NumProcessThreads: Integer;
var
  HSnapShot: THandle;
  Te32: TThreadEntry32;
  Proch: DWORD;
  ProcThreads: Integer;
begin
  ProcThreads := 0;
  Proch := GetCurrentProcessID;
  HSnapShot := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
  Te32.dwSize := SizeOf(TTHREADENTRY32);
  if Thread32First(HSnapShot, Te32) then
  begin
    if Te32.th32OwnerProcessID = Proch then
      Inc(ProcThreads);

    while Thread32Next(hSnapShot, Te32) do
    begin
      if Te32.th32OwnerProcessID = Proch then
        Inc(ProcThreads);
    end;
  end;
  CloseHandle (HSnapShot);
  Result := ProcThreads;
end;
```

Code to create empty zip stream

```
procedure TShellZip.CreateEmptyZip;
const
  EmptyZip: array[0..23] of Byte  = (80, 75, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
var
  Ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  //criar um arquivo zip vazio
  Ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Ms.WriteBuffer(EmptyZip, SizeOf(EmptyZip));
    Ms.SaveToFile(ZipFile);
  finally
    Ms.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to automate the shell to do this. As you have discovered that's not easy to do cleanly.

You can use the ZIP component that ships with Delphi, [TZipFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Zip.TZipFile). If you have an older version of Delphi, one that does not include this component, then you should use a third party component like [Abbrevia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpabbrevia/).

Comment: Thank you David. The unit TZipFile exists only in Delphi XE2. You can help me make this work in Delphi 2010?

Comment: Well, it's XE. Anyway, this question doesn't specify a version, so this answer is fine. For you with 2010 you need to use abbrevia, for example.

Comment: I use [ZipForge](http://www.componentace.com/zip_component_zip_delphi_zipforge.htm) for my application zipping tasks.